# The screen freezes when processing logic in NetSuite's client script

Tags: javascript, ajax, netsuite

Hello NetSuite developers.

When a button is pressed, a function that processes business logic along with notification is being used in Client Script.

The business logic works normally, and there is no problem with the process, but the moment the OK button in the Confirm notification is pressed, the screen freezes until all processes are finished.

This phenomenon seems to cause the user to perceive an error as if it occurred!

I am posting my code below. It is a long code, but it would be appreciated if you let me know how the screen does not freeze after checking.

```
dialog.alert({
            title: 'NOTICE',
            message: 'PROCESS START'
        }).then(function (result) {

            var isArrAggr = true;

            var link = url.resolveScript({
                scriptId: getParameterFromURL('script'),
                deploymentId: getParameterFromURL('deploy')
            });

            var arrayParam = getParameterFromURL('array');
            arrayParam = JSON.parse(arrayParam)

            var std = new Date();
            var c_year = std.getFullYear();
            var c_month = std.getMonth();
            var c_date = std.getDate();
            var c_hour = std.getHours();
            var c_minute = std.getMinutes();
            var c_second = std.getSeconds();
            std = c_year + ',' + c_month + ',' + c_date + ',' + c_hour + ',' + c_minute + ',' + c_second;

            var array = [];
            arrayParam.forEach(function (val) {
                array.push(val)
            });

            for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
                var ivNum = '';
                const clSearch = search.create({
                    type: '----------(customRecord)',
                    filters: [
                        ['----------(customField1)', search.Operator.IS, array[i].transaction_id]
                    ],
                    columns: [
                        '----------(customField2)'
                    ]
                });
                clSearch.run().each(function (result) {
                    ivNum = result.getValue('----------(customField2)');
                });

                if (ivNum === '') {
                    isArrAggr = false;

                    NS.jQuery.ajax({
                        url: link,
                        async: false,
                        type: 'POST',
                        data: {
                            array: JSON.stringify(array[i]),
                            rUserId: runtime.getCurrentUser().id,
                            std: std
                        },
                        dataType: 'text',
                        success: function (data) {
                            // 1: Success / 0: Failure
                            if (parseInt(data) === 1) {
                                NS.jQuery('#row' + i + ' > td:nth-child(10)').html("<span>OK</span>");
                            }
                        },
                        error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                            NS.jQuery('#row' + i + ' > td:nth-child(10)').html("<b style='color: #ff0000 !important;'>Failed</b>");
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
            // End for

            if (isArrAggr)
                dialog.alert({
                    title: 'NOTICE',
                    message: 'NO'
                });
            else
                dialog.alert({
                    title: 'NOTICE',
                    message: 'PROCESS ENDED'
                });

        }).catch(function (reaseon) {
            dialog.alert({title: 'CAUTION', message: 'PROCESSED FAILURE. \n Cause: ' + reaseon})
        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refactor to run "const clSearch = search.create" in promise mode.

You're doing an asynchronous dialog, but then a synchronous search inside the promise fulfillment. That's most likely what's causing the bottleneck.

Comment: Thanks for posting the answer! As you said, I changed the search object to'promise' and executed it, but unfortunately, the bottleneck continued to occur.
Surprisingly, this was happening in Chrome, IE, and Edge, and in Firefox, I saw ajax working and changing the DOM. (In other browsers, the screen changes at once after all processing is finished!)